# Function that get ACF fields value before saving

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, advanced-custom-fields, save-post

Rewrited question:
There is a similar question [HERE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65889/get-advanced-custom-fields-values-before-saving) but I don't know how to combine it with my code.

I have a function that relay on acf checkbox field. It is working fine but I have to update the post twice, because get_field(‘checkbox_field’) returns the data after the other content.

Here is an example:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'my_func');
function my_func($post) {
    $pageID = 123; // certain page id
    $cp_field = get_field("custom_field", $pageID);
    if ($post['post_type'] != 'my_post_type'
        || $post['post_status'] == 'trash'
    )
        return $post;

    if(!get_field('checkbox_field')) { // The problem field
        // ... do something here
        return $post;
    } else {
        return $post;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked [ACF's documentation site](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/) and [the plugin's support forum](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/advanced-custom-fields)?

Comment: I know what I have to use - http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/actions/acf_save_post/ but don't know how to implement it with my func :(

Comment: Sometimes I think that people just don't read my questions...

Comment: Have a look in this [post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/65902/39121). This happens because you use wordpress hook and yours field doesn't save to DB that's why you have to save twice.